# Has Biden held far fewer press interviews than Obama or Trump in an equivalent time period?

Tags: united-states, president, media, joe-biden

According to one CJR [article](https://www.cjr.org/special_report/frictionless_white_house_briefings_press_corps.php):

> Biden conducted far fewer interviews during his first months in office than Trump did: nine in his first hundred days, compared with fifty-one for Trump and forty-six for Barack Obama. The press has gotten the briefing back, yes, but we’ve lost privileged glimpses into the West Wing. [...]
>
> The WHCA has chided the president for holding fewer press conferences than his predecessors.

Are those stats (for the 100 days) accurate and did the same pattern continue in the subsequent months?

Comment: IMO this would be better on skeptics, but it’s still on topic here.

Comment: Remember to take context into account when looking at anything.  There's currently a global pandemic (which is largely uncontrolled in the USA), so press interviews involve health risks to everyone involved that aren't typically present.

Answer (score 31):

There aren't numbers for the first 100 days AFAIK, but [The American Presidency Project](https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/statistics/data/presidential-news-conferences) has a feature that tracks these numbers by year, dating back to President Calvin Coolidge.

President Biden has held less formal news conferences in his first year as compared to past Presidents. However, these numbers exclude impromptu interactions with the press which [was](https://www.politico.com/story/2019/08/22/trump-marine-one-press-briefings-1471629) largely [popularised](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiextOdh67zAhUwlEsFHTnGCZYQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.washingtonpost.com%2Flifestyle%2Fstyle%2Ftrumps-favorite-venue-for-making-news--or-avoiding-it--is-right-in-front-of-the-presidential-chopper%2F2019%2F10%2F23%2F7a1df9ca-de4d-11e9-8dc8-498eabc129a0_story.html&usg=AOvVaw2kB_OcGyOAI5HQdEr_rBQo) by President Trump.

| President | Number of news conferences held in their 1st year |
| --- | --- |
| Bush, H.W. | 31 |
| Clinton | 38 |
| Bush, W. | 19 |
| Obama | 27 |
| Trump | 21 |
| Biden | 7 |

A list of news conferences counted by The American Presidency Project can be found [here](https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/advanced-search?field-keywords=&field-keywords2=&field-keywords3=&from%5Bdate%5D=&to%5Bdate%5D=&person2=&category2%5B%5D=73&items_per_page=25).

Comment: Note that the question is about "interviews," which includes but is not limited to the "news conferences" counted in this answer. As a result, the question reports higher numbers than are shown in this answer. (Having said that, the numbers presented here support the original claim)

Comment: It looks like even if you added in those news conferences, it would only double the number up to 14. Of course the year isn't over yet.

Comment: Good point @T.E.D. - what would the equivalent number be for President Trump?

Comment: @Cullub - I got curious, but gave up after the 3rd screen that didn't even get me back earlier than 2020. (Dayum, but that dude loved to talk). I don't know about 2016, but for 2020 (admittedly, an election year, so in no way comparable) it would be **a lot**.